# how to communicate with an smtp serverusing socket library in python

Tags: python, smtp

i am trying to print the output of HELP command not the output of me connecting to the SMTP server
that is how my code looks like

**import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect(("localhost",25))

s.send(b'HELP')

print s.recv(1024)**

that is what i am geting
[image]

that is what i want to see
[image]

Comment: I cannot see how this is related to information security, i.e. it is off-topic here. This is instead a programming question and maybe also a question of how SMTP works (please read the standard, they exist for a reason).

Comment: sorry mr steffen if i will ever wanted to post a question like this one shoud i post it on stackoverflow

Comment: Yes, stackoverflow.com is the site for programming problems. Note that each of the various stackexchange sites has help easily available, which also covers what is on-topic at this site, how to best ask questions, how to properly format code etc. Please make yourself familiar with this before posting.

Comment: okey ,mr steffen i will do my best have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ending all commands with \r\n, and utf8-encoding the commands, and utf8-decoding the responses, like so:

```
import socket

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('smtp.gmail.com', 587))

msg=s.recv(256).decode("utf-8")
print('s->c: ' + msg)

msg="EHLO testsmtp\r\n"
s.send(msg.encode("utf-8"))
print('c->s: ' + msg)

msg=s.recv(256).decode("utf-8")
print('s->c: ' + msg)

msg="HELP\r\n"
s.send(msg.encode("utf-8"))
print('c->s: ' + msg)

msg=s.recv(256).decode("utf-8")
print('s->c: ' + msg)

msg="quit\r\n"
s.send(msg.encode("utf-8"))
print('c->s: ' + msg)

msg=s.recv(256).decode("utf-8")
print('s->c: ' + msg)
```

This script produces the following when run:

```
s->c: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP li4-20020a170906f98400b00a26f5eb0554sm8457680ejb.63 - gsmtp

c->s: EHLO testsmtp

s->c: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [154.160.17.225]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8

c->s: HELP

s->c: 214 2.0.0  https://www.google.com/search?btnI&q=RFC+5321 li4-20020a170906f98400b00a26f5eb0554sm8457680ejb.63 - gsmtp

c->s: quit

s->c: 221 2.0.0 closing connection li4-20020a170906f98400b00a26f5eb0554sm8457680ejb.63 - gsmtp
```

Comment: it worked thanks u all i gotta do is to attmpt to understand what u said to me thanks alot